# Solve the ODE $y'' = (y')^2$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, solution-verification

I am asked in a past question paper to solve the following ODE: $$ y'' = (y')^{2}$$

To solve this, I began by equating $$y' = u$$

Differentiating both sides $w.r.t.x$ $$ \frac{d^{2}y}{dx^{2}} = \frac{du}{dx}$$

And therefore substituting back to out original equation I got:
$$  \frac{du}{dx} = u^{2}$$

Rearranging $$\frac{du}{u^{2}} = dx$$

Integrating $w.r.t.x$ I got

$$ \frac{-1}{u} = x+C$$ and substituting back $u$
$$ \frac{-dx}{dy} = x+C$$
$$ =x + \frac{dx}{dy} = C$$
$$=\frac{-dx}{x+c} = dy$$
$$ \log(\frac{1}{x+c}) = y$$
$$ -(x+c) = e^{y}$$

Is my answer and method correct?

**EDIT** As pointed out by **@MtGlasser**

We can re-write the **D.E** as $$ \frac{y''}{y'} = y'$$

Which is of the form :
$$(ln(y'))' = y'$$

Integrating on both sides we get
$$ ln (y') = y + c$$
And taking exponent on both sides and re-arranging we get
$$ e^{-1}e^{-y} dy = dx$$

Integrating we get the asnwer $$ e^{-(y+1)} - C = x$$

Comment: You forgot the other constant of integration $\Longrightarrow ke^y$

Comment: The DE is just  $(\ln y')'=y'$  you have derivatives on both sides of the DE. Integrate.

Comment: @MtGlasser That seems like a very direct and easy method to solve. Thank you for pointing it out.

Comment: You're welcome @Kalvin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your method is mostly correct, although the steps could be made more clear for the latter part and also you didn't include another constant of integrating after the last integration. Note you can stop once you have expressed $y$ in terms of $x$, unless it says in the question to express $x$ in terms of $y$.

We have

$$-\frac{dx}{dy}=x+C_{1}$$
$$\frac{dx}{dy}=-x-C_{1}$$
$$-\frac{dx}{x+C_{1}}=dy$$
$$\color{red}{C_{2}}-\ln(x+C_{1})=y$$
$$\implies y(x)=C_{2}-\ln(x+C_{1})$$

Answer (score 2):

You could even do it faster switching variables
$$y'' = (y')^{2} \implies -\frac {x''}{[x']^3}=\frac {1}{[x']^2}\implies x''=-x'$$
Reduction of order
$$p'=-p \implies p=x'=c_1\,e^{-y}\implies x=-c_1 \,e^{-y}+c_2\implies y=\cdots$$

Comment: You've forgotten what $y$ equals!

Comment: @Eli. I did not ! This was on purpose but I shall make it clearer. Cheers :-)