# What Operations create a unique function?

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

When solving [this ODE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4253864/solve-the-ode-y-y2)
\begin{align}
y''=(y')^2,
\end{align}

I noted that it could be integrated in two ways (given that $y'\neq0$):
\begin{align}
\frac{y''}{y'}&=y'\implies\ln(y')=y+k\\
&\implies y=-\ln(kx+k_0).
\end{align}
or
\begin{align}
\frac{y''}{(y')^2}=1\implies \frac{1}{y'}=c-x\\
\implies y=-\ln(cx+c_0),
\end{align}

which are obviously equivalent.

But looking just halfway through each solution, we can equate $y'$s to get the solution without needing to integrate again:
\begin{align}
e^{k+y}=\frac{1}{c-x}\implies y=-\ln(kx+k_0).
\end{align}

In short, I don't quite get what operations create a unique function. Performing algebraic operations does not create a unique equation, but if you integrate afterwards you get two unique equations? Is there a formalism to what I'm trying to get at here? A comprehensive list of sorts on a Wikipedia page?

At this point I realize I'm not even sure how unique functions are defined, the only explanation I've been given being that a function substituted into another yielding the identity $0=0$ means that they were not unique to each other.

Note:
I've tagged a few subjects which I think may contain the answers but I'm open to suggestions that they are not relevant or what may be relevant.

Comment: Existence and Uniqueness theorems, like the [Picard-Lindelof theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picard%E2%80%93Lindel%C3%B6f_theorem), talk about the more mathematical ways a differential equation both has a solution, and a solution that is unique to it given boundary conditions. But it seems like your question is more about the philosophical property of [consistency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consistency). Which are you more interested in actually? Have a look at the wikipedia pages for both

Comment: When you use your halfway solutions, you could get extraneous solutions. For example, equation $x=1$ could be written as $x^3=1$, then $x^3-x=1-1=0$, but this equation has extraneous roots $x=0$ and $x=-1$.

Comment: @IvanKaznacheyeu thanks for the response. I'm somewhat familiar with uniqueness/existence theorems when it comes to solutions of differential equations, it is indeed not what I'm looking for. From reading the wiki page on consistency, it seems like I may be able to answer my question if I dig into logic.